# How do you convert a wide time series data frame into a long data frame?

Tags: r

Context, I am looking to melt a wide time-series data frame into a long data frame. This way I can plot the data in ggplot2 and build a stacked area graph. The time series is not regular (missing some weekends and holidays)

The current data frame looks like

```
df
    date        item_1    item_2     item_3 ...
1 1992-03-23      8.63     7.609     1.6546 ...
2 1992-03-24      7.98     7.634     1.6533 ... 
...
```

How do I convert the above data frame into

```
    date        variable    value
1 1992-03-23    item_1       8.63
2 1992-03-23    item_2      7.609
3 1992-03-23    item_3     1.6546
2 1992-03-24    item_1       7.98
```

using the following code I get the error

```
> melted_df = melt(df)
Using as id variables
Error in as.Date.numer(value): 'origin' must be supplied
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to specify the `id.vars` as second argument in the melt function and it works:

```
require(reshape)
df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("1992-03-23", "1992-03-24")),
                 item_1 = c(8.63, 7.98),
                 item_2 = c(7.609, 7.634),
                 item_3 = c(1.6546, 1.6533))

melt(df, "date")
```

you will get:

```
        date variable  value
1 1992-03-23   item_1 8.6300
2 1992-03-24   item_1 7.9800
3 1992-03-23   item_2 7.6090
4 1992-03-24   item_2 7.6340
5 1992-03-23   item_3 1.6546
6 1992-03-24   item_3 1.6533
```

hope this helps

Comment: This worked.  I needed to specify "date" in the formula.

Comment: how do I specify a subset? e.g. new_data_frame (where:  variable == item_1 or variable ==   item_2)

Comment: i would do this with `require(dplyr)` and then just:

`df_new <- melt(df, "date") %>% filter(variable == "item_1" | variable == "item_2")`

Answer (score 0):

Or with `gather`

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(date = as.Date(c("1992-03-23", "1992-03-24")),
                 item_1 = c(8.63, 7.98),
                 item_2 = c(7.609, 7.634),
                 item_3 = c(1.6546, 1.6533))

df %>% gather(variable, value, -date)
```

gives,

```
        date variable  value
1 1992-03-23   item_1 8.6300
2 1992-03-24   item_1 7.9800
3 1992-03-23   item_2 7.6090
4 1992-03-24   item_2 7.6340
5 1992-03-23   item_3 1.6546
6 1992-03-24   item_3 1.6533
```